# Unable to write text to TextBox from QR scanner

Tags: c#, winforms, qr-code

I have this QR code:

[image: QRCode]

Text inside is `<QR><DOM>DOM2201064</DOM><DOP>95237</DOP><ART>D-RSP_BOK-S-420-16-Z5</ART><QTY>128</QTY></QR>`

On my phone and PC, I have installed the `Barcode to PC` application, so my phone is now working as a QR scanner. I can scan codes and text from QR is automatically inserted e.q. into WordPad, Excel, etc.

Unfortunately, I have a problem inserting scanned text into TextBox input even if it is focused, visible, and editable. I tried to add KeyDown and TextChanged events, but it doesn't react on any scan.

Where can be a problem?

Comment: Is it possible that your application runs with admin privileges?

Comment: What is this "Barcode to PC" program and how does it work? We can't help you if none of us know exactly how it's meant to work.

Comment: @NineBerry I always start VS Studio as admin, so I supose, that runned application has admin privilages too.

Comment: @Dai https://barcodetopc.com/ - QR scanners are used in production, so I have to use phone. It works well everywhere except in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely that your application runs with admin privileges while the "Barcode to PC" software doesn't.

There are two possible solutions:

Either don't run your own application with admin privileges.

Or start the "Barcode to PC Server" software with admin privileges (Make sure the software is not already running)

[image]